# removing spaces between table values in php

Tags: php, html

In my HTML code inside php, I tried to create a table and I have created it. But I am getting space in between each table data. Here is the code

```
    <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
     {
     $num=$_POST['input1'];
     $n=$_POST['input2'];
     echo "<table border=1 >" ;

     for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
     {

       $ans=$num*$i;
       echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> $num  <td>";
        echo "<td> * <td>";
        echo "<td> $i <td>";
         echo "<td> = <td>";
        echo "<td> $ans <td>";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "</tr>";

      }
      }
       echo "</table>";
     ?>
```

[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/08pZU.png)

I want to remove the small empty box in between 2 values. Please help me with this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Remove the <br> for one

Comment: well! i didn't use any empty TD tag here.

Comment: Also, why is your end table outside of your isset bracket set? When the table is started inside

Comment: do you mean changing this `"<td> $num  <td>"` to that `"<td>$num<td>"`??

Comment: tried!! but no use. :-(

Comment: You're not closing your td tags

Comment: it's unclear what extra space you mean. Can you post an image? Maybe you mean the non-collapsing borders?

Comment: you are not closing your <td> it should be "<td>$num</td>"

Comment: Thank you @AdamHull it worked :-) Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Thank you @Jeff for your time.

Comment: thank you @clearshot66 it worked. Thank u so much

Comment: @KaminiIshwarya No problem!

Comment: @AdamHull can you add this as an answer so it can be accepted & easily found in the future?

Comment: I have added this as a answer please accept

Answer (score 3):

Close your `<td>` like `</td>` tags and change your code around like this:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++)
     {

       $ans=$num*$i;
       echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> $num  </td>";
        echo "<td> * </td>";
        echo "<td> $i </td>";
         echo "<td> = </td>";
        echo "<td> $ans </td>";
        echo "</tr>";

      }

       echo "</table>";
}
```

Shouldn't have a `<br>` in there and your bracket for the `isset..` should be outside the table close element

Answer (score 0):

when using `<td>` you need to make sure you are closing the tags `<td>Code Here</td>`

```
for($i=1;$i<=$n;$i++) { 
$ans=$num*$i; 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td> $num </td>"; 
echo "<td> * </td>"; 
echo "<td> $i </td>"; 
echo "<td> = </td>"; 
echo "<td> $ans </td>"; 
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>"; 
}
```